# How to watch PGN at different speeds?

Tags: software, programming, pgn, online, windows

I am looking for a program for Windows or an online service for viewing PGN at variable speed.  I know that lichess has fast and slow speed, but I want more adjustable settings.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, sometimes people can be a little harsh towards new contributors. To avoid having your question poorly received, I'd probably edit your post to clarify that you are asking for a particular website or software that allows you to enter PGNs. Remember that a PGN is just a text file.

Comment: I don't know any software doing adjustable speed, some has 2, max 3 speeds - you might end up writing your own.

Comment: @Drako PC programs, had the ability to adjust replay speed.

Answer (score 1):

My own web application can help you

https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzle/editor.php

(1) Paste the PGN text into the 'PGN import' tab.

(2) Adjust the speed of animation on the 'diagram' tab.

(3) Click 'download animated diagram'.